# MongoDB aggregate by time window

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am struggling to create an aggregate query for my MongoDB database.

The database is quite large (+10GB) and therefore manually aggregating is very slow even in short time window (tens of thousands of documents).

The document sample always follows this structure:

```
{
  "_id":ObjectId("568285c5693a7336bb16c817"),
  "DetectTime":"2015-12-29T13:08:21Z",
  "Node":[
    {
      "Type":["Flow","Statistical"],
      "SW":["Nemea","HostStatsNemea"],
      "Name":"cz.cesnet.nemea.hoststats"
    }
  ],
  "EventTime":"2015-12-29T13:07:05Z",
  "Description":"Horizontal port scan",
  "ConnCount":254,
  "CeaseTime":"2015-12-29T13:07:46Z",
  "Format":"IDEA0",
  "Category":["Recon.Scanning"],
  "ID":"924c76d4-7c4d-45d8-b1b1-3dc36cf47729",
  "Source":[
    {
      "IP4":["192.168.0.254"],
      "Proto":["tcp"]
    }
  ],
  "FlowCount":254,
  "CreateTime":"2015-12-29T13:08:21Z"
}
```

What is important for me is the `Category` and `DetectTime` by which I want to aggregate. With `DetectTime` I want to achieve aggregation by `N` minutes for each `Category` and sum the `FlowCount` for each aggregation. I am really struggling with it since the `DetectTime` is not a Date but string and therefore I cannot work with it properly.

I am really stuck and any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Change the date fields to real BSON Date objects. Really. Moreover, find the code responsible for storing these as strings and get that fixed. 1. You will be able to do what you want both simply and in a performant fashion. 2. The current string representations as wasting a lot of storage space, as a BSON Date is internally stored as an integer ( milliseconds since epoch ) and will use significantly less space. Those are the two cases you need to put to your boss. If you don't do that then it's just another problem to fix down the line.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I didn't realise the difference in storage representation and space-saving. This is what persuaded my colleagues to change it. Now the whole DB is changed and I created the needed query in less than an hour. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with `DetectTime` being `string` not `datetime` object. I am quite sure that you must be doing comparison of `datetime`somewhere in your logic. To compare, you need to convert `string` to `datetime` object by doing this

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
detectTime = dt.strptime("2015-12-29T13:08:21Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

You can do this for all your entries once and store it in MongoDB.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response but unfortunately I cannot change the schema of the document (it is given by our company standard). I already have this kind of logic in my python code I want to implement it in MongoDB itself.

Comment: @PetrStehlik If you can change your data structure then your best bet is mapReduce.